# For Loop pattern from 654321,54321.. to 1

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, nested-loops, counting

Using Java,

I am trying to use nested for loops to make a chart that prints out 654321 to 1,

Example,

```
654321

54321

4321

321

21

1
```

The following code prints out a close enough example but instead of decreasing from the front decrease from the back,

```
654321

65432

6543

654

65

6
```

It is sort of doing what I want put not exactly, how would you make it count down from the beginning?

```
public class test_for_loops{

   public static void main (String [] args){
      int lines = 6;
      for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
       for (int j = lines; j >= i; j--){
         System.out.print (j + " ");
         }   
      System.out.println();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop is printing `j` which always is starting from `lines` which is set to `6`. So your result is expected. If you want to print starting from different value then you need to figure out expression which will calculate that value. For first line it should be 6, for second 5, third 4... you see the pattern?

Comment: people shouldn't really give the answer out, it's counterproductive for OP, who just needs to debug the code a little longer until finally figuring out where's the flaw in the current logic

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, that makes a lot more sense, I wasnt thinking about it stating from 6, instean just knew it had to have 6 characters in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
int lines = 6;

for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){

    for (int j = lines - i + 1; j >= 1; j--){

        System.out.print (j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 
2 1 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

1.)  simply start `i` from `0` and set `j=lines-i`

2.) Traverse `j` till `1`

```
    int lines = 6;
      for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
       for (int j = lines-i; j >= 1; j--){
         System.out.print (j + " ");
         }   
      System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 
2 1 
1
```

Working

```
 i   = 0 
     j (6 - 0 => 6)    6 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 

 i   = 1 
     j (6 - 1 => 5)  5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 

 i   = 2 
     j (6 - 2 => 4)  4 , 3 , 2 , 1 
  .
  .  
 i   = 5 
     j (6 - 5 => 1)  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't decrease lines, so j is always set to 6 on the start of inner loop. Try this:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
  int lines = 6;
  int jcounter = lines;
  for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
   for (int j = jcounter ; j >= 1; j--){
     System.out.print (j + " ");
     }
  jcounter--;   
  System.out.println();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 6;
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Explanation: use outer loop to control the length (the max number) of each line. Use inner loop to print the elements of each line using that length. I hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the order in which the for loop goes

```
public class test_for_loops{

   public static void main (String [] args){
      int lines = 6;
      for (int cLine = lines; i > 0 ; i--){
       for (int j = cLine; j > 0; j--){
         System.out.print(j + " ");
         }   
      System.out.println();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are too close, We need to do the changes only in 2 places, i.e.

**1.) Outer loop** make i=0 and let it run till **< lines**

**2.) Inner Loop** make **j = lines-i** and let it run till **> 0**

```
public class test_for_loops{
   public static void main (String [] args){
     int lines = 6;
     for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
       for (int j = lines-i; j > 0; j--){
         System.out.print (j + " ");
       }   
       System.out.println();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you want to do this in a for-loop, but the best way I can think of doing it is by creating an integer array, then printing out the values in the array by their index. With each iteration through the loop, we start printing out the part of the array that is is 1 position less (i.e. we start by printing all 6 digits in the array (6-0=6), then we print the first 5 digits in the array (6-1=5), and then the first 4 (6-2=4) and so on.)... The only problem with this is when you get to printing position. The loop never reaches zero because it jumps out when you hit zero, or you get an array-out-of-bounds exception if you do not. So the best solution I could come up with is below - I had to print out the last digit:

```
public class test_for_loops{
    public static void main (String [] args){\
    int lines = 6; 
    int digits[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
    for (int i = 1; i < lines; i++){
        for (int j = lines; j >= i; j--){
            System.out.print (digits[j-i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");    
    }
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
654321
54321
4321
321
21
1
```